# Euphemistic pee-pee/wee-wee: which refers to the organ and which refers to urinating?

Tags: american-english, phrase-usage, euphemisms

Does one *pee-pee* with his *wee-wee*, or does he *wee-wee* with his *pee-pee*? Is one phrasing more typical than the other?

That is to say: How is *pee-pee* used more commonly- as "to urinate" or as "penis"? And vice-versa for *wee-wee*. I'm curious if there are widespread or regional customs.

Both are informally correct in American English. *Pee-pee* and *wee-wee* are both used as nouns/verbs for urination (*"I went pee-pee"*, "*He pee-peed next to the wall*") and both are used as euphemisms to refer to the penis.

This likely doesn't apply to UK or Australian English, at least based on [this post](https://www.superlinguo.com/post/171530395104/a-pee-vs-a-wee) about "pee" vs. "wee" and part of speech.

Comment: What's your question?  When I was a small kid I tee-teed with my tee-tee. But other kids did different things -- a lot depends on family custom.

Comment: I'm wondering if usage is entirely individualized (family custom) or if there are more widespread customs. To rephrase, is pee-pee more commonly used to mean "to urinate" or "penis"? And the same question for wee-wee.

Comment: When you find an authoritative source, let us know. You'd hafta survey every home with children in the UK and the US, for starts.

Comment: You might check in [parenting.se] chat even.  A lot of families are choose not to use any baby talk or slang for body parts.

Comment: @JohnLawler If a question is difficult to answer, that should be a good reason to leave it open, no?

Comment: @alphabet - Not so much 'difficult to answer' as 'there is no definitive answer'. To me (UK) _wee[-wee]_ is baby talk and _pee_ is a colloquial euphemism for _piss_.

Comment: "wee-wee" meaning to urinate or urine is in many commercially-available dictionaries, but not meaning genitalia; "pee-pee" not with any meaning; although Wiktionary has both with both senses. That's probably the best guidance you'll get about which is most common ("wee-wee" for urine). But maybe someone has done dialect studies on this, it's often surprising what people do.

Comment: Whatever term is in the family idiolect, it often  (not always) can be used to refer to the equipment, the activity, and the product.  For example, I've never heard the penis called a **tinkle** (which can refer to the activity and the product) but I've heard **pee-pee** and **wee-wee** refer to all three. We shouldn't let commercial lexicography stand as the authority here. This subject is grist for the sociolinguist.

Comment: Since there are no reliable studies, all answers are opinions. I voted once to close this question as opinion-based, but can't do it again for some reason. Apparently ELU likes giving its opinions on peepee and weewee.

Comment: If families are roughly evenly split in how they use these terms, then that **is** the answer (rather than a reason for concluding that the question is unanswerable).

Comment: Just to state the bleeding' obvious - little girls go *wee-wee* and *pee-pee* too, without the aid of a penis. As to answering the question, the 'fact' that reputable dictionaries define both to mean the act of urination, rather than the organ used, suggests to me that that is the dominant usage. Oh, and to pick up on another point, I ain't letting no sociolinguist use my *pee-pee* as grist ....

Comment: @JohnLawler If there's no available information, I think the right choice is to leave a question unanswered, not to close it. There isn't a problem with the question itself; it's just that nobody (here, currently) knows the answer.

Comment: One difficulty I've encountered in answering the question is that the noun form can refer to both the *penis* as well as *urine*. For instance, "Did you make *pee-pee*/*wee-wee*?" or "Did you have a *pee-pee*/*wee-wee* accident?" "Is there pee-pee/wee-wee on my rug?" So it isn't sufficient to search by part of speech; you'd need to also individually categorize corpus results semantically, while hoping your corpus was relatively representative of the audience likely to use *pee-pee* or *wee-wee*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this enthusiastic discussion, despite its value as refreshment.

Comment: @JohnLawler Turns out there *is* a study on this; see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat amazingly, this topic has actually been studied. The paper ["Early Genital Naming" by Fraley *et al.* (1991)](https://journals.lww.com/jrnldbp/Abstract/1991/10000/Early_Genital_Naming.3.aspx) surveyed 54 boys in the Greater Cleveland area and asked them what name(s) they used to describe their genitals.

Of them, 12 gave "peepee" and 3 gave "weewee." This is, of course, an extremely small study from a single region; I'm not sure if there are any studies about what term(s) children use for urine. But it does suggest that, when referring to genitalia, "peepee" is the more common choice.

Comment: more common in Cleveland in 1990, at least, among 54 children. From this we can conclude ... ?

Comment: It's a start! It shows the question is in principle answerable, if there was any doubt.